# How to delete "non-deleteable" files left over from sed -i

Tags: bash, sed, rm

So, there are a plethora of questions on this site regarding why using `sed -i ...` creates a bunch of random files. For me, I ran `sed -i ...` on a directory and it created a temp file for basically every non-text file in the directory. These files are named `xxx.!nnnn!yyy.ext`, where the `!nnnn` part seems to be generated by `sed -i`.

So, without removing the entire directory and re-cloning the repo, how do I delete them?

```
$ rm bin/.!27249!CassExporter.jar
$ -bash: !27249: event not found
```

Comment: Use quotes `rm '.!27249!CassExporter.jar'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find FOLDER -name '*!*' -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

When filename has `!` it tries to expand a history event starting with the text next to `!`.

You should disable history expansion using `set +H`

```
# disable history expansion
set +H

# remove all files starting with DOT and having !
rm bin./.*!*

# re-enable history expansion
set -H
```